# Simple TELNET Server

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, telnet

I have written a telnet server and client, but I don't receive a response from the server and I don't know where the problem is.

**SERVER**

```
import socket
import subprocess

def handle_client(client_socket):

MAX_RECV_BUFFER = 1024

allowed_commands = ["ls, cd, ls -l"]

recv_size = 1
while recv_size:

    data_buffer = client_socket.recv(MAX_RECV_BUFFER)
    command = data_buffer.decode("utf-8")

    if not data_buffer:
        print("Client just disconected")
        break

    recv_size = len(data_buffer)

    if command in allowed_commands:
        response = run_command(commad)
        client_socket.send(response.encode("utf-8"))
    data_buffer = ""

def init_server(server_address, reuseAddr=True):

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    server_socket.bind(server_address)
except socket.error as serr:
    print(str(serr))

server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
if hasattr(socket, "SO_REUSEPORT"):
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)

server_socket.listen(5)

print("Server listen at {}:{}".format(server_address[0], server_address[1]))

try:
    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

        print("Client has connected {}:{}".format(client_address[0], client_address[1]))

        handle_client(client_socket)

except KeyboardInterrupt as kerr:
    print("Server is closing...")
    client_socket.close()
    server_socket.close()

def run_command(commad):
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(commad, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
shell=True)
except OSError as oserr:
    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_server(("127.0.0.1",8080))
```

**CLIENT**

```
import socket

def init_client(server_address):
connected = True
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Connecting {} to server ...'.format(server_address))
client_socket.connect(server_address)

while connected:
    # allowed__commands = ['ls, cd, ls-l']
    try:
        if server_address[0] == '127.0.0.1':
            message = input('\nlocalhost@localhost' + '>> ')
        else:
            message = input(server_address[0] + '@' + server_address[1] + 
'>> \n')
        print('Sending message: {}'.format(message))
        client_socket.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))

        recv_data(client_socket)

    except IOError as e:
        print('Error: {}'.format(e))

    except Exception as e:
        print('Other error: {}'.format(e))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            connected = False
def recv_data(client_socket):
recv_size = 1
MAX_RECV_BUFFER = 1024
while recv_size:
    data_buffer = client_socket.recv(MAX_RECV_BUFFER)
    message = data_buffer.decode('utf-8')
    print('Received data: '.format(message))

    if not data_buffer:
        break
    recv_size += len(data_buffer)

data_buffer = ''
client_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
init_client(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: TCP is a stream-oriented transport, not message-oriented. There is no 1:1 relationship between `send()` and `recv()`. For what you are attempting to do, you need to ensure that the sender always sends a line break after each message, and the receiver reads until it encounters the line break, before then processing the sent data. You are not handling that correctly on either end. Also, this is NOT a Telnet client/server, as the [actual Telnet protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854) is not being implemented. All you are doing is writing a wrapper for the system console. That is not Telnet.

Comment: i worked it out, thank you!